# Hacer foco a un componente en REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, componentes, focus

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi intencion es que al dar click en un elemento del header en este caso al de **Votar**
quiero que se mueva (haga un foco) automaticamente al componente **MenuVotacion**. Probé haciendo foco a un input y funciona pero con un componente no lo hace.

```
    const votar = useRef(null);

    const focusVotar = () => {
        votar.current.focus();
    }

    return (
        <div className='ContenedorWeb'>
            <Header focusVotar={focusVotar}/>
            <MenuVotacion ref={votar}/>
            <ComoFunciona />
            <SobreNosotros />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Supongo que quieres hacer focus en las opciones que contiene `Heaer` o a todo el componente ?

Comment: Quiero hacer foco al componente MenuVotacion, es decir un scroll automatico hasta esa seccion.

Comment: por favor agrega el código de `Header`.

Comment: Listo, ya lo agregue. Igual la función se ejecuta correctamente, el problema esta dentro del codigo principal.

Comment: una disculpa, he confundido que quieres hacer fucos a `Header` , por favor coloca `MenuVotacion` y el `css` que quieres aplicar o acción a realizar al hacer focus

Comment: Creo que no entendio bien la idea de lo que planteo, tengo una web de una sola pagina la cual tiene un header en el que podes seleccionar Votar, Como Funciona o Sobre nosotros; lo que quiero es que al hacer click sobre uno de ellos me lleve a la respectiva sección, pj. click en Votar me lleve a la seccion de votar, el cual es un componente. Son movimientos en la misma pagina seria solo un movimiento del scroll.

Comment: Has probado con `votar.current.scrollIntoView()` en vez de `votar.current.focus()` ?

Comment: Me tira el mismo error que al usar el focus, cree un elemento p en modo de prueba e intente enfocarlo y funciona perfectamente, el problema es cuando intento enfocar un componente.

Comment: De cuál error hablas? No lo veo en ningún lado.

Comment: Lo pude solucionar poniendo un elemento p vacio por encima del componente y hacerle foco al elemento con la funcion .current.scrollIntoView()

Comment: Si has solucionado tu problema, por favor agrega la solución como respuesta, para que otros tengan referencia de solución a problemas similares.

Answer (score 0):

La solucion que es encontrado es crear un paraffo

vacio encima del componente y en vez de enfocar el componente, lo hago con el elemento p

Answer (score 0):

En tu div tienes que colocar el atributo tabIndex="0"

```
<div tabIndex="0"></div>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).